# DEM files and r2stl()

Tags: r, dem

In R The Volcano dataset has elevation values, but is not a DEM file. How can I convert my DEM files (from earthexplorer.usgs.gov) so that the I can access all the elevation values in a matrix (what is returned by volcano)? I am trying to use r2stl() with the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [raster](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/index.html) package:

```
library(raster)
dem = raster("a_dem')
# plot with R
library(rasterVis)
plot3D(dem)
```

[image]

```
# convert the raster to a matrix (as Volcano)
demmat = as.matrix(dem)
```

Now, you can apply the same procedure as in  [r2stl/demo/Maungawhau.R](https://github.com/cran/r2stl/blob/master/demo/Maungawhau.R)

```
z = demmat
x = 1:dim(demmat)[1]
y = 1:dim(demmat)[2]
library(r2stl)
r2stl(x, y, z, filename="dem.stl", show.persp=TRUE)
```

Result with [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/):

[image]

Comment: Thanks @gene  .as.matrix() creates z values, but I'm still getting strange results. Most of  my dems are spiky and if it is smooth r2stl seems to create a 1x1 x something less than 1, even if my x and y values are not equal-distorting the model. Is there a way to get a solid stl file with r2stl that is closer to the results from writeSTL (which just creates a surface)  
`dem <-raster("dems_10m.dem")  
 demmat <-as.matrix(dem)  
 dem[is.na(dem)] <- 0   
 z <-  demmat    
 x <- (1:nrow(z))    
 y <- (1:ncol(z))  
 r2stl(x,y,z, filename="crater.stl")`